adding click event inside ngfor is not working
Why is the click not triggering inside the ngFor? I tried adding console log and it does not even fire.
HTML code
<ng-container *ngFor="let store of getLocationIds()">
  <a onclick="alert('clicked')" style="cursor: pointer;">Test Link</a>
  <a (click)="redirectToUrl(store.url)" class="location-link" style="cursor: pointer;">{{ store.locationId }}</a>
  <ng-container *ngIf="store !== getLocationIds()[getLocationIds().length - 1]">, </ng-container>
</ng-container>

getLocationIds(): { locationId: string, url: string }[] {
  const stores = this.nonRetailProperty?.nonRetailAssociatedStores || [];
  return stores.map(store => ({
    locationId: store.locationId,
    url: store.url
  }));
}

redirectToUrl(url: string): void {
  console.log('1234', url)
  window.open(url, '_blank');
}


Maybe my suggestion is using the <button> element instead of <a> element. With Bootstrap, you can make the button to be displayed as a link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/

Your code works fine. I suspect that you are clicking the "Test Link" not the element with {{ store.locationId }}.

no it does not, when i try to put the testlink outside the ngfor it works but when i put it inside ngfor it no longer worls

i was able to fix it by remove the getlocationsid function and using *ngFor="let store of nonRetailProperty?.nonRetailAssociatedStores"

Try adding href="#" to <a> and $event.preventDefault(); to (click).
<a href="#" (click)="$event.preventDefault(); redirectToUrl(store.url)"...


still the same Sir, the console log does not even fire
